# Show that $\mathcal F=\{A\cap B: A \in \mathcal B_1, B \in \mathcal B_2\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal B_1$, $\mathcal B_2$ two $\sigma$-algebras of subset of $\Omega$. Define $\mathcal F=\{A\cap B: A \in \mathcal B_1, B \in \mathcal B_2\}$. Show it is a $\sigma$-algebra as well.

If I'm not wrong, this should be the intersection of two $\sigma$-algebras, which is trivially a $\sigma$-algebra. But written in this way I can't prove $(A\cap B)^c=A^c\cup B^c \in \mathcal F$, and without the second postulate I can't neither say it is a $\lambda$-system. Does anyone have any guess?

I would really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: As grndl, points out, $\mathcal{F}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. On the other hand, if $\mathcal{B_i}_{i \in I}$ is an arbitrary large family of $\sigma$ algebras, the intersection $\cap _{i \in I} \mathcal{B}_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true.

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$, $\mathcal B_1 = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3\}, \Omega\}$ and $\mathcal B_2 = \{\emptyset, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \Omega\}$. Then,
$$\mathcal F = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2\}, \Omega\}$$
is not a $\sigma$-algebra because $\{1,3\} \notin \mathcal F$.

Note that $\mathcal F \neq \mathcal B_1 \cap \mathcal B_2 = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$.

Comment: Could you explain why this statement, where you define B1 and B2 to be the smallest sigma algebra, wouldn't work if if B1 and B2 were larger? Wouldn't $$\{1,3}$$ be in $\F$ anyways?